# Initializing static const member with other static const member

Tags: c++, static, constants

I have 2 classes with static const members which I want them to be identical, so I use other static const member of other class, and I want to initialize those members with the value of the common class.
It looks like that:
A.h:

```
class A { 
public:
    static const std::string a;
};
```

A.cpp:

```
const std::string A::a = "hello";
```

B.h:

```
class B {
public:
    static const std::string b;
};
```

B.cpp:

```
const std::string B::b = A::a;
```

C.h:

```
class C {
public:
    static const std::string c;
};
```

C.cpp:

```
const std::string C::c = A::a;
```

The problem is I cannot initialize static const members with other static member, since the static members are initialized in the beginning of the program run, and the value of A::a is not available when trying to initialize B::b and C::c so I get segmentation fault.

What can I do to solve this design problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a separate function to get a *string* to perform an initialization and avoid initialization order fiasco:

```
const std::string initialize() {
    static const std::string initializer = "meow";
    return initializer;
}
```

Then you might do the initialization as follows:

```
class A {
    public:
        static const std::string a;
};

const std::string A::a = initialize();
```